# Ajax content submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have the following code, which takes a response from the Cardspring servers and attempts to send it to our site to be stored in our database. I'm having trouble getting the ajax to work correctly. As I watch the heroku server logs, it seems as it the ajax isn't sending a POST to our server -- there's no log entry for the ajax request. Here's what the ajax code looks like:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
     {
        $('#contactform').submit(function(event) {
            $('.submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            cardSpringResponseHandler = function(response){
                if((typeof response.error) != "undefined")
                {
                    var error = response.error;
                    var reason = response.reason;
                    alert(error + '    ' + reason);
                }

                else
                {
                    alert(response.token + '    ' + response.last4 + '   '+ response.brand + '    ' + response.brand_string + '    ' + response.expiration);
                    alert('Thank you, your card is registered!');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url:'www.url.com/me',
                        async: false,
                        data: {"token": response.token,"last4": repsonse.last4,"brand": response.brand,"brand_string":response.brand_string,"expiration": response.expiration}.serialize(),

                         error: function () {
                                alert('Error');
                             }
                    });

                }

                alert('Hello 2');
            };
            alert('adding card');
            CardSpring.addCard(cardSpringResponseHandler
            , {
                publisher_id : '{{ CARDSPRING_APP_ID }}',
                security_token : '{{ securityToken }}',
                timestamp : '{{ timestamp }}',
                hmac : '{{ digestedHash }}'
            }, {
                card_number : $('.card-number').val(),
                exp_month : $('.expiration-month').val(),
                exp_year : $('.expiration-year').val(),
                user_id : '{{ csid }}'
            }, "all");
            alert('card added');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a snippet of urls.py, to show the url:

```
url(r'^me/$', accountInfo),
```

Here's what the server side code looks like, as a django view:

```
def accountInfo(request):
    #after CS.addCard is sucessful, this adds the credit card Token to our DB...
    print request.method
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "in account info"
        print "expiration = " ,
        #print request.POST['expiration']
        print "request ="
        print request
        try:
            cardToAdd = Cards(csID = request.COOKIES.get('csID'),token = request.POST['token'], last4 = request.POST['last4'], cardType = request.POST["brand"] ,typeString = request.POST['brand_string'],
            expDate = request.POST['expiration'])
            cardToAdd.save();
            json_data = json.dumps({"HTTPRESPONSE":"sucess"})
            return HttpResponse(json_data, mimetype="application/json") 

        except:
            json_data = json.dumps({"HTTPRESPONSE":"fail"})
            return HttpResponse(json_data, mimetype="application/json")
```

The initial print request.method runs on the first load of the page, with method = GET. The server doesn't print out any other requests, which makes me think the ajax code isn't running

The alerts (at least some of them) do occur. They always occur in this order:

- adding card
- card added
- response.token, response.last4, etc
- Thank you, your card was added

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Thank you for your help -- I'm very very rusty with ajax and javascript

Comment: Is this a same domain AJAX request? Cross domain requests are not allowed (assuming a non CORS supporting browser). What are the Chrome Developer Tools showing about that POST request? Does Fiddler2 show any POST activity?
Also, the shown code does not actually submit a form, it only adds a submit event handler. Do you submit the form by yourself?